# File Download through Struts action hangs a while

Tags: servlets, struts, liferay, liferay-6, document-library

I am currently developping on a Liferay server.

```
[liferay-portal-6.1.10-ee-ga1 + tomcat-7.0.25]
```

In some cases my users download files from the Document-Library.

What happens is that when they do so with the following type of url

```
[$LIFERAY_HOST]/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=[$OBNOXIOUSLY_LONG_UUID]&groupId=[$MY_GROUP_ID]
```

The file download takes ages to end.

In fact the download itself does not take more time than required. But it seems that the response is not closed.

Most download clients (including Firefox, wget, wireshark ...) don't seem to be noticed of the end of the response.

Result is that they hang for **no actual good reason**.

Worst is that my Firefox users have the impression that their download is taking ages for files that are really small (like 20 seconds for 8kb ... thay say, and are right, it is unacceptable).

I've tried to dig in my stacks and look around in liferay's sources but I can't figure where that latency comes from.

I've tried to look in the way of this thread (which looked really promising) https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11838689

But this did not apply to my problem. I've forced all filter classes to spit log messages and they all seem to execute in a few milliseconds (at most, one second all together).

I tried to inspect httpservletrequest's outputstream flushing and closing, they are all executed rightfully and cleanly ... I'm starting to loose hope and faith in myself ... I'm sad, I feel dirty, I need coffee ... Help me ... please !

---- Edit : Answer ----

In fact my problem was related to the GZip filter (in a way that I did not spot at my first tries.
On my exact version rp's answer is not the actual solution but it is on a lot of close versions.
If you come across the same issue, broxse either rp's Answer (down below) or this :

[www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/21186157#_19_message_21215343](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/21186157#_19_message_21215343)

Comment: Somethings that might help: What document store are you using and do you have any custom development?

Comment: That is indeed a very good question. My documentLibrary files are stored on my server's filesystem (cf line dl.store.impl=com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.FileSystemStore in my portal.properties we did not override it in the portal-ext.properties).
There are of course custome developpements on our liferay portal but none in the current workflow of file serving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is an issue with Liferay. Searching the Liferay bug tracker I found [LPS-29323](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-29323) whose description matches yours.

Fortunately the fix appears to be simple.

You can view the [pull request that fixes the issue](https://github.com/hhuijser/liferay-portal/commit/5e22ad07bf281a09f1b6a090838a1790d8952a18) or add these lines to `WEB-INF\liferay-web.xml`

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ETag Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>^(/c/document_library/get_file|/c/message_boards/get_message_attachment|/c/wiki/get_page_attachment)(\?.*)?$</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I just left work :'( I'll try this tomorow in the morning ;) But anyhow this seems odd as I already investigated the filter lead ...
Maybe I did not investigate right.
I tell you asap !

Comment: Your answer made me dig far more deeply in this filter situation.
Turns out that my real problem was the gzip filter that appeared to work all properly on my first checks.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! I should add your own findings as an answer.

Comment: I mean... *you* should add your own findings as an answer :P

Comment: I'm not sure that an answer would be more efficient than an edited question ;)
Plus, there a to few people who read pultiple answers on StackOverflow to justify adding another answer :)